# True or False: if $(a_n)^2$ converges and $a_n\le 0$ for every n, then $a_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

My attempt: if $(a_n)^2$ converges, then it converges to a finite limit, then by the definition of the limit we get that : $|(a_n)^2 - L| < \epsilon $ 
 then I opened up the absolute value and got: $L-\epsilon < a_n^2 < L + \epsilon $. (I really wanted to take a square root and end it here but if any sides of the inequation has a negative value then my proof is false, I tried to come up with a counter example and I couldn't find one too, but I think here I can choose the $\epsilon $ as I like since the limit exists so if I took $\epsilon = \frac {L} 2$, I would have all positive and be able to take square root on all the inequality sides. 
 I wanna make sure if my proof is correct, and if it is, then why choosing one specific $\epsilon $, holds for a proof. 
 if it's not any explanation would be pretty much appreciated. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the following fact: if $f$ is continuous at $\ell$ and $x_n \to \ell$, then $f(x_n) \to f(\ell)$? If yes, you could use this: what $f$ can you take to go from $a_n^2$ to $a_n$?

Comment: $L-\epsilon < a_n^2 < L + \epsilon $ is equivalent to  $-\sqrt {L+\epsilon} < a_n <\sqrt { L - \epsilon} $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a_n^2 \to L$. Note that $L \geq 0$ since $a_n^2 \geq 0$ for all $n$. Then by continuity of $\sqrt{\cdot}$, we obtain $-a_n= \sqrt{a_n^2} \to \sqrt{L}$ and thus $a_n \to -\sqrt{L}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the case $L=0$ separately using $\epsilon'=\sqrt{\epsilon}$, so let assume $L>0$.

WLOG you can set $b_n=-a_n$ to work with all positive quantities and get rid of annoyances with sign and inequalities.

Let set $L=\ell^2$ with $\ell>0$, we get

$$|b_n-\ell|=\dfrac{\overbrace{|{b_n}^2-\ell^2|}^{\to 0}}{\underbrace{|b_n+\ell|}_\text{bounded}}\le \frac 1\ell|{b_n}^2-L|\to 0$$

The proof essentially relies on showing that the denominator is bounded but this is trivial since $|b_n+\ell|=b_n+\ell\ge \ell>0$ using the positivity of $b_n$.

You can try writing the proof directly with $a_n$ but it requires a bit of gymnastic to deal with inequalities properly.